# Get selected UITableViewCell on touch down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, touch

I need to get the the currently selected UITableViewCell as its tapped. So upon my finger touching the screen/cell I want to run a method from which I can say something as simple as:

```
selectedCell = cell;
```

`cell` being the one I just tapped and `selectedCell` being a copy I store.

I am using a custom subclassed UITableViewCell which is why I think I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TouchDown** 
- setSelected:animated: is called on the cell itself on touch down here, you can inform a cells delegate

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [self.delegate willSelectCell:self];
}
```

declare custom cells delegate as property of the cell

```
@property id<MyCellDelegate> delegate;
```

**TouchUP** 
save the cell in the delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
_selectedCell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

just pay attention to the fact that Cell Views can be reused

Comment: I figured this might be suggested, sorry I didn't mention, but possibly because of my custom cell, this doesn't get called on pressing my cell. Would having a custom cell make any difference to this?

Comment: Isn't `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` get triggered on touch up?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight likely, sorry

Comment: I've set a breakpoint in my cell subclass in the setSelected method and its never called when I tap my cells at all.

Comment: - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%@", self);
} -- works fine in a custom subclass

Comment: @JoshKahane Did you try capturing `- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state` calls in your custom cell? I'm not sure if it would work, though.

Comment: Could it be that the subviews I have on my cell block `setSelected` from being called? Also, `willTransitionToState` is not called upon tapping either.

Comment: highly unlikely, but could it be that the tablview has doesnt allow a selection? that would 'block' both methods

Comment: There is a bit of particularly wrong information in this answer. As described correctly in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1653798/18961, setSelected is called on touch up, rather than on touch down. setHighlighted is called on touch down.

Answer (score 13):

Just implement setHighlighted:animated: method on your own custom tableview cell like this.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    NSLog (@"setHighlighted:%@ animated:%@", (highlighted?@"YES":@"NO"), (animated?@"YES":@"NO"));
}
```